# How to stop Python from crashing when the input is supposed to be an int but the user inputs a different data type?

Tags: python, input

```py
num = int(input("Number: "))
if num != int:
    

def summer():

    summed = 0
    for i in str(num):
        summed += int(i)
    print(summed)
    if len(str(num)) != 5:
        print("Type a number with 5 letters")
    else:
        print(*str(num), sep=", ")


summer()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try`

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input('Number : '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Value is not an integer, repeat')
        continue
```